# How to change server name in IIS 10 after renaming server

Tags: iis, iis-10

Just wanted to check, what's the best way to rename the server name within IIS, have preinstalled IIS on the new 2022 Windows server no sites have been created yet, but will need to rename the server and IIS before we do.

Is this the best way to do this as seen in the attached image, rename the server in IIS by right click and then select "rename" and then saving its configuration by closing it.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Yes, you can just rename the server in IIS. Click on the server name and press F2 or rightclick-rename.

Comment: @samwu Thank you Samwu, just wanted to confirm this.